# Running IBM WebSphere Liberty Profile as Microsoft Azure Web Site

Tags: java, azure, cloud, websphere-liberty

I am attempting to run an IBM WebSphere Liberty profile Java application as a Microsoft Azure web site. Following the Microsoft documentation for a custom Java web site, I have not able to get the application started.  Microsoft says it is possible, but helpful documentation is scarce.

Has anyone successfully deployed a WebSphere liberty Profile application to Azure?

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

IBM has issued a press release that says "IBM and Microsoft will make key IBM middleware such as WebSphere Liberty, MQ, and DB2 available on Microsoft Azure", IBM and Microsoft to Offer Greater Choice in the Hybrid Cloud

https://www-03.ibm.com/press/us/en/pressrelease/45196.wss